# Cisco 1841 Dual WAN (Failover) + OpenVPN

Tags: networking, cisco, openvpn, router

I can setup Dual WAN in Failover mode on Cisco 1841 however I can't seem to get OpenVPN working. I need both WANs to use OpenVPN but can't seem to find any guides on the internet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you terminating OpenVPN? Can you post a diagram of your setup and configuration of 1841?

Comment: I'm trying to use a Paid VPN service on other end which uses OpenVPN.

Comment: And you want to terminate it on the Cisco 1841?

Comment: I want to encrypt all traffic between my Cisco 1841 and the paid VPN service server i.e. not let ISP see my unencrypted traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco routers do not support OpenVPN Client or Server, i.e. they cannot terminate OpenVPN Tunnel. You will need to setup a OpenVPN server behind your Cisco Router.